# Adding values to new column based on predicate

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe with a bunch of people and the company, they're affiliated with:

```
Id|Name  |Company        
1 |Hanzo |Bank of America
2 |Bertha|Disney         
3 |Bob   |Swiss Bank
```

Now I'd like to add a new column with the type of company, they belong to:

```
Id|Name  |Company        |Type
1 |Hanzo |Bank of America|Bank
2 |Bertha|Disney         |Entertainment
3 |Bob   |Swiss Bank     |Bank
```

How would I go through the dataframe, filter the company column and extract the values into a new column? Something like this:

```
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    if dataset[['Company'].str.contains('BANK')][i]:
        dataset['Type'] = 'Bank'
    else:
        dataset['Type'] = 'Unknown'
```

Comment: And how are you going to fill in "Entertainment"?

Comment: Are they always seperated by `|`?

Comment: @13aal No, it's a .csv so my representation is actually a bit stupid..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) if need process 2 or more conditions:

```
#mask for Entertainment type
ent_companies = ['Disney', ...]
mask1 = dataset['Company'].isin(ent_companies)
#mask for Bank type
mask2 = dataset['Company'].str.contains('BANK', case=False)
dataset['type'] = np.select([mask1, mask2], ['Entertainment', 'Bank'],default='Unknown')
```

For process one condition only better is [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
dataset['type'] = np.where(mask1, 'Bank', 'No bank')
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That is true, but I think how to determine whether or not a company is in the `Entertainment` group is a subjective matter. I was mostly intered in the filtering mechanism.